# Google Chart Visualization API tqx option broken?

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

This works

curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13pXb7Kek010B6s8Ez3h6yX4qF92MgvV4uMk71dJhe3o/gviz/tq?**tqx=out:html**&tq=select%20A,B,C%20#gid=0&pubhtml?widget=true&headers=false'

So does this:

curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13pXb7Kek010B6s8Ez3h6yX4qF92MgvV4uMk71dJhe3o/gviz/tq?**tqx=out:csv**&tq=select%20A,B,C%20#gid=0&pubhtml?widget=true&headers=false'

This does not

curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13pXb7Kek010B6s8Ez3h6yX4qF92MgvV4uMk71dJhe3o/gviz/tq?**tqx=out:tsv-excel**&tq=select%20A,B,C%20#gid=0&pubhtml?widget=true&headers=false'

Instead I get:

google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"1469006009","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Species -- \u0027Cultivar\u0027 -- Pot Size","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"Count","type":"number","pattern":"General"},{"id":"C","label":"Price","type":"number","pattern":"[$$]#,##0.00"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Cedar, Eastern White -- \u0027Skybound\u0027 -- #10 Grow bag (42 liters)"},{"v":37.0,"f":"37"},{"v":120.0,"f":"$120.00"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Cedar, Eastern White -- #5 trade

which appears to me to be JSON output.

How do I get tab delimited output?

It's documented here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source#request-format

Do I have a typo?

I have also posted this to the google [visualization-api] group, but after two days I have received no response.

Comment: couldn't find a problem with the `curl` either...